# Web Video Streaming from IP Camera using OzekiSDK

Tags: asp.net-mvc, ip-camera, pelco

We have built a Web Application in ASP.Net / C# for IP Camera monitoring and streaming. In the camera streaming web page we would like to stream from more than 1 camera in the same time and same page, is this possible ?? Any guidance here

As most of the provided examples are opening a new page from the browser to stream the video, while we want to maintain working on the same page, and control the streaming from that page.